# supporting migration, software build and dependency analysis

Tags: java, deployment, ide, installation

I am searching for standards, methodologies and technologies (software systems) supporting:

- software building (lots of them)
- dependencies management (in compilation, program start-up) (maven, SCons)
- migration dependencies to new versions (e.g. libraries) (any ??)

Mostly I'm interested in Java tools, but please don't restrict.
Do only *ant* and *maven* build Java software?

I asked uncle Google but I need to know everything.
Any answer will be helpful.

Comment: You can compile java by hand (on the command line), use make, use a shell script, use a batch file, whatever you desire. Whether that's comfortable is a different question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following things are tools, but what kind of standards are you searching for?

some examples from my side:

Software building [gradle](http://gradle.org/), [buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/), [phing](http://phing.info/trac/), [CMake (C/C++ like)](http://www.cmake.org)

[CI Systems](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix)

Dependency Management like you mentioned Maven2/3

Comment: I'm searching rather for any how-to, methodology about upgrading project to new versions of libraries and technologies.

Comment: A simple approach to update e.g. libraries is to create a branch (by a VCT of your choice) update to the new lib release and do testing...if this works well integrate the change into your dev/rel line. Build process can be a heavy job if you have already implemented build process (build, deployment, test etc.) than it depends what you expect from a new technology ? (reduce of costs etc. ?)